# How to special character selector field in dataweave?

Tags: mule, special-characters, dataweave, mulesoft, mule-esb

I am transforming a `JSON` input to `XML` output and I have a field with name `Antigüedad` with special character in it. I am following the below dataweave. `XML` is unable to generate this field. Can you please let me know where I am going wrong ?

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere", encoding="UTF-8"
---
Acceptor @("Antigüedad": payload.Acceptor."Antigüedad")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have sample data but this works for me:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere", encoding="UTF-8"
%var data = Acceptor @("Antigüedad": "Antigüedad"): {

}
---
Acceptor @("Antigüedad": data.Acceptor.@"Antigüedad"): {

}
```

Comment: I have already tried this, but it is not working. Though sample request is propagating the value for the field, at the end when I pass this field as JSON body in postman, the field is not generating in the XML.

Comment: Sample input data please along with the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
 Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

in HTTP headers.